# How to test LifeCycles and EvenEmitters in Stencil with Jest

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I am using Stenciljs and Jest.
I am having a hard time testing events triggered in the lifecycle (componentDidLoad).

I am able to enter the lifecycle, but unable to test the .emit() event.

I have tried the following:

.spec.ts

```
it('should spyOn componentDidLoad', () => {
   const component = new App();
   jest.spyOn(component, 'componentDidLoad');
    let eventSpy = jest.fn();
    component.document.addEventListener('toScroll', eventSpy);
    expect(component.componentDidLoad()).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Here is the situation at a glance:

.tsx

```
  @Event() toScroll: EventEmitter<void>;

  componentDidLoad() {
    this.toScroll.emit();
}
```

.spec.ts

```
it('should spyOn componentDidLoad', () => {
    const component = new App();
    jest.spyOn(component, 'componentDidLoad');

    // need a way to test the emit() here.    

    expect(component.componentDidLoad()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The (logical) following error occurs:

● render component › should spyOn componentDidLoad

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Stencil is instantiating your EventEmitter I would recommend using [end-to-end testing](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing) using `newE2EPage`:

```js
    import { newE2EPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';

    it('should emit an event on load', async () => {
      const page = await newE2EPage();

      await page.setContent(`
        <my-app></my-app>
      `);

      const toScroll = await page.spyOnEvent('toScroll');

      await page.waitForChanges();

      expect(toScroll).toHaveReceivedEvent();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I will have a look at our e2e implementation and take your advise in consideration.

For now I have resolved the scroll as following:

component.toScroll = { 

emit: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
};
expect(component.toScroll.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();